# creating a keyboard shortcut to open a specific folder/directory

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, directory

I have dropbox installed. So I would like to create a keyboard shortcut to open my dropbox directory in nautilus ? what is the command that I have to put in the 'command' field ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tryed the nautilus command with the path you want?

```bash
nautilus Dropbox/
```

Here is the usage : `nautilus [options] URIs...`

Check [Nautilus man Page](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/nautilus).

Comment: it worked when I removed the "~/" so the final command was: `nautilus Dropbox/` You might want to edit it :) Thanks